# How to find the next available slot in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I was practicing on CodingBat when I came across this problem I couldn't quite get right. Given an array of positive integers, I must create an array of length "count" containing the first even numbers from the original array. The original array will contain at least "count" even numbers. My code is below, though I know that everything below the first if statement does not work and the "counter" variable is basically useless.

```
public int[] copyEvens(int[] nums, int count) {
  int counter = 0;
  int[] countArr = new int [count];
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] % 2 == 0) {
      //what to put here?
    }
  }
  return countArr;
}
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if its a 0 that means its available

Comment: I don't see a problem in a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int[] copyEvens(int[] nums, int count) {
  int counter = 0;
  int[] countArr = new int [count];
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length && counter < count; i++) 
    if ((nums[i] % 2) == 0) 
        countArr[counter++] = nums[i];
  return countArr;
}
```

School stuff... right?

Comment: Fixed it... Your exit condition was wrong,,, It had to be (counter < count)... and something I'm always not sure about evaluation order.
in some languages  if (nums[i] % 2 == 0)  evaluates (2 == 0) 1st, so I allways use  if ((nums[i] % 2) == 0) .

Answer (score 2):

The following is incorrect:

```
  if (i == count) {
```

This checks the position in the *input* array, rather than the position in the *output* array, against `count`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be comparing the
counter... which starts at 0 .. so you need to add 1 as I am pretty sure count does not include 0 as an index.

Thus,

```
if((counter+1) ==count)
```

should replace the original.